# Detect current location & calculate distance with predefined location for website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps, geolocation

I want user's current location to be detected by browser and with predefined location from textbox or label that should calculate total distance between two places. It is something like zomato shows in any restaurant list. I want to know how can I do it for my vb.net website? Please suggest me any links which suggest this things.

Answer (score 1):

- to get the user's current location you'll need to use [Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) API.
- to get current Address from coordinates you'll need to use [Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview) API

To use Google Maps and these API you will have to [generate an API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/). And make sure to enable the above mentioned API's for the generated API Key.

Example Code:

```
var map, infoWindow;

// initialize a map with given coordinates (call it in HTML!).
function initMap() {
  var egypt = new google.maps.LatLng(26.8206, 30.8025);
  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: egypt,
    zoom: 6,
  });

  getCurrentLocation();
  getCurrentAddress(map, infoWindow, pos);
}

// set Map to current location.
function getCurrentLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Browser supports geolocatin (get current location).
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function (position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude,
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('You are here.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setZoom(15);
        map.setCenter(pos);

        getCurrentAddress(map, infoWindow, pos);
      },
      function () {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      }
    );
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation.
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(
    browserHasGeolocation
      ? // ? 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.'
        'Error: Unable to get your current location.'
      : "Error: Your browser doesn't support geolocation."
  );
  infoWindow.open(map);
}

// get current Address from coordinates (pos) using Geocoder API.
function getCurrentAddress(map, infowindow, pos) {
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  if (geocoder) {
    geocoder.geocode({ latLng: pos }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log(results[0].formatted_address);

        // create marker at current position.
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pos,
          map: map,
        });

        // open an infoWindow above marker & set its content to current address.
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        console.log('Geocoding failed: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@StupidRomeo Use Geolocation, Custom Controls, Autocomplete API(optional) , Distance Matrix Service.
Geolocation for attempting to locate the user's current user. Here is an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) Note that this is upon accepting the user's that his/her location to known.
The Google Maps Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client can detect. This document describes the protocol used to send this data to the server and to return a response to the client.
An input box with (autocomplete api) helps ease the user's convience to find a correct location that Google Maps would find. Here is an example provided in the [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). Using the autocomplete feature of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.
Then lastly would be fetching the two point using the custom [button](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) and will call the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)
Sample response of Distance Matrix Service API:

```
"rows": [ {
 "elements": [ {
  "status": "OK",
 "duration": {
 "value": 70778,
 "text": "19 hours 40 mins"
 },
 "distance": {
 "value": 1887508,
 "text": "1173 mi"
 }
 }
```